# How to show FullScreenSlideshowViewController on ViewDidLoad

Tags: ios, xcode, uiimageview

I am new to iOS development, I have created android app where app gets sets of images (sometimes over 100 images) from urls and loads into imageView with zoomEnabled Inside ViewPager.

Now I want to create same app for iOS, I have found this lib [ImageSliderShow](https://github.com/zvonicek/ImageSlideshow). Problem with this is it shows fullscreen ONLY when user did tap on selected image. I have been struggling to `presentFullScreenController` on `viewDidLoad` with no lock.

I only want image to be shown in fullScreen, example:

Select Category A From CategoryVC -> Loads ImageSlideVC, gets set of images from server, show in FullScreenView.

How can i achieve this? Adding this:

```
slideshow.presentFullScreenController(from: self)
```

on `viewDidLoad` didn't work:

```
@IBOutlet var slideshow: ImageSlideshow!

let kingfisherSource = [KingfisherSource(urlString: "https://images.unsplash.com/photo-1447746249824-4be4e1b76d66?w=1080")!,
         KingfisherSource(urlString: "https://images.unsplash.com/photo-1447746249824-4be4e1b76d66?w=1080")!,
         KingfisherSource(urlString: "https://images.unsplash.com/photo-1463595373836-6e0b0a8ee322?w=1080")!]

override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()

    slideshow.setImageInputs(kingfisherSource)
    slideshow.presentFullScreenController(from: self)

}
```

I dont get any error, output is same as before (shows slideshow in smallview with no zoom)

Please help

**EDIT**

by doing in viewDidAppear, after split second view is loaded its loads into fullscreen. First its smallview then shows in fullscreen. I think i have to do something inside setImageInputs

this is what its looks like :

```
 open func setImageInputs(_ inputs: [InputSource]) {
    self.images = inputs
    self.pageControl.numberOfPages = inputs.count

    // in circular mode we add dummy first and last image to enable smooth scrolling
    if circular && images.count > 1 {
        var scImages = [InputSource]()

        if let last = images.last {
            scImages.append(last)
        }
        scImages += images
        if let first = images.first {
            scImages.append(first)
        }

        self.scrollViewImages = scImages
    } else {
        self.scrollViewImages = images
    }



    reloadScrollView()
    layoutScrollView()
    layoutPageControl()
    setTimerIfNeeded()
}
```

Comment: provide your try code..

Answer (score 0):

try to do it in `viewDidAppear`

```
@IBOutlet var slideshow: ImageSlideshow!

 override func viewDidAppear(_ animated: Bool) {
    super.viewDidAppear(animated)

    slideshow.setImageInputs(kingfisherSource)
    slideshow.presentFullScreenController(from: self)

}
```

Presenting viewController in ViewDidLoad is a bad practice.

Comment: Thank you, @arthur-sahakyan its shows fullscreen when i do it in viewDidAppear, however first its loads smallView then loads into fullscreen. i think i have to do something in setImageInputs. Also when in fullscreen view if  user taps fullview disappears and shows again in fullview..

Comment: @Joe Joiden I only can recommend you to use another library, because here code is actually right.